# How can I get in post the context_data?

Tags: django, django-views

In a CreateView I have the following code:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
        send_confirmation_email()
```

When a form is submited, I want to send an email, but in the email function, I need some data from the context(what was submitted).

Also I want this to happen if everything is ok, so also on get_success_url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing two things. `context_data` is the data you send to the template. You can get it with `self.get_context_data()` if needed.

The submitted data can be found in `self.request.POST`.

However, in a create view, you can use the [`form_valid()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.form_valid) method to process the form data.